# How to Insert items into multiple Arrays in Node.js & MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

This might be a weird question but I believe nothing is completely impossible.

I have a List of Users in MongoDB, each user has among other things, properties array which is currently empty.

In Excel sheet, I have a data that represents each user's properties which I want to programmatically insert in each user's properties array.

Importing excel sheet is fast and easy to populating each user's properties is what gives me the problem.

I have added userId, and PropeId, from the users and the properties they bought, so Identify them as seen below
[image: Assignment table]

```
router.put('/importdata', async (req, res)=>{
// upload queries
const imported = req.files.importdata;
 const uploadpath = path.resolve(`public/excel_maneger/uploads/ ${imported.name}`);
if (imported.truncated) {
  throw new Error("Uploaded File is too big, should not be morethan 20 MB");
}
await imported.mv(uploadpath);
 const file = render.readFile(uploadpath);
  const sheets = file.SheetNames;
  const data = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    const sheetname = sheets[i];
    const sheetData = render.utils.sheet_to_json(file.Sheets[sheetname]);
    sheetData.forEach((item) => {
      data.push(item);
    });
  }

 try {
   const users = await User.find({role: 'Customer'})   
       for(let i = 0; i < users.length; i++ ){
            data.forEach((d) => {
               if(users[i].id == d.id){
                 User.updateMany(
                   {},
                   {
                     $set: {
                       properties: {
                         propeId: d.propeId,
                       },
                     },
                   },
                   (err, d) => {
                     if (err) console.log(err);
                   }
                 );
               }
            });
       }
          
        


 } catch (err) {
   console.log(err)
 }
  
})
```

The Problem is that this code updates everyone on the Database (including non specified users) with the same information, Please I need help, I am trying to import 11 thousand users information from excel to database

Answer (score 0):

When you are updating your `User.updateMany()`, You are not passing in the Id.

What it does is it when `if` statement is `true`, it updates all the user, You can use [findByIdAndUpdate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate)

Also you should be using `async/await`. Since that is what you are using to find the user

```
await User.findByIdAndUpdate( users[i]._id,{ $set: { properties: { propeId: d.propeId }}})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have finally figured where I made the mistake, I am supposed to use $in: operator to access multiple Ids as desired.

Here's the solution:

```
  data.forEach((d) => {
      User.updateMany(
        { _id: { $in: [d.id] } },
        {
          $push: {
            properties: d.propeId,
          },
        },
        (err, d) => {
          if (err) return false;
        }
      );
    });
```

Above solved the problem amazingly